# CSS-property for numbers

Tags: css

Is there a way to automatically add a CSS-property, like letter-spacing, to every number but not to the other characters?

Comment: Nope and css is not a place for automation

Comment: @krish “CSS is not a place for automation” – but just because of the way it’s designed, not because of some inherent property of styling. Automation *could* be designed into (a new version of) CSS. See Less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, there is no way of doing that using just CSS. You’ll need to wrap the numbers in `<span>` (or similar) elements and then use that as a hook for writing your CSS selector.